# Remove scrollbar from ScrollView programmatically in Android

Tags: android, scrollview, scrollbars

How can I remove the scroll bar from a ScrollView programmatically?

`setScrollBarStyle()` only changes only the style of the scrollbar.

I want to access the xml attribute `android:scrollbars` programmatically. Is there any way to do that?

`android:scrollbars`  Defines which scrollbars should be displayed on scrolling or not.

Comment: Related/dupe: [Hide Scrollbar of HorizontalScrollView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258814/hide-scrollbar-of-horizontalscrollview)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The following two method calls will remove the scrollbars in your scrollview:

```
view.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
view.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

Comment: also he can do it in XML , for example , using : android:scrollbars="none" would hide all scrollbars.

Answer (score 4):

In java add this code:

```
myScrollView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
myScrollView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

In xml add following attribute to your `ScrollView`:

```
android:scrollbars="none"
```