# Hide Scrollbar of HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, view, scrollbar, horizontalscrollview

How can I get rid of the scrollbars on a [`HorizontalScrollView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html)?

Answer (score 275, accepted):

Add the following to your xml:

```
android:scrollbars="none"
```

Or hide the scrollbars programmatically:

```
view.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false); 
view.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

Comment: it seems there is a bug that ignores android:scrollbars="none" on many devices so programmatic approach is the right way. thanks :-)

Comment: Actually is not a bug, it depends if you are placing the xml code correctly. :)

Comment: @Machado what is the correct way then? Putting android:scrollbars="none" on the HorizontalScrollView element has no effect.

Comment: as mentioned by @Benito, do it programmatically. XML method failed for me at places, while through code it worked at all times.