# How To Use HorizontalScrollView Only When Needed

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I am displaying text and images in a ListView with HorizontalScrollView if the text and images is too long for the screen size but I thought it would only be there if it is needed.

But even when there is no need for the HorizontalScrollView cause the text and images fit in screen it still appears for every row and it is all in tabs so this makes swiping from tab to tab irritating cause your finger catches the HorizontalScrollView and not the whole tab.

And all textviews ect... are in one layout file so I can't choose only certain rows.

[image]

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView7"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"/>




  </LinearLayout>

  </HorizontalScrollView>


 View v=infla.inflate(R.layout.main_tab_layout, null);


        TextView tv1=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            ImageView iv1=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            TextView tv2=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            ImageView iv2=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);



        tv1.setText(text1[position]);
            iv1.setImageResource(text2[position]);
            tv2.setText(text3[position]);
            iv2.setImageResource(text4[position]);


            if(text3[position].matches("")) {
                tv2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }



            if(text4[position]==R.drawable.ic_star){
                iv2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }



            return v;
        }
```

Comment: Are you using setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) for the useless view? if yes, try change them to  View.GONE

Comment: Yes I am using View.GONE code above

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12258874/1576416

Answer (score 0):

You are not hiding the ImageViews. There is no drawable on them that is why it looks like there is nothing there but since width and height are hardcoded, it will take space.

set Visibility to gone for ImageViews that are not being used.